# Torchtext functions in Newest version analogue

Tags: nlp, version, torchtext

Good day all, i'm trying to solve task, where it was used previously `torchtext.dataset.TranslationDataset`, `torch.data.Field` and `torch.data.BucketIterator`. But, after updating they were removed and i don't know how it can be used now. Has anybody faced with this problem, how have you solved it? I'd be the greatful, if you share a link with advice if it's possible.

I've tried to read docs and find info on the Internet, but unsuccessfully. It always cite `torchtext.legacy`, but it doesn't have it in up-to-date versions. I understand, that i can download to it's version, but don't want this yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the imports in the newer version of torch and their latest documentation

- `torchtext.dataset.TranslationDataset` -> [torchtext.datasets.TranslationDataset](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datasets.html#torchtext.datasets.TranslationDataset)
- `torch.data.Field` -> [torchtext.data.Field](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#torchtext.data.Field)
- `torch.data.BucketIterator` -> [torchtext.data.BucketIterator](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html?#bucketiterator)

Let me know if you have trouble importing them